# In Java, how to allocate given amount of memory, and hold it until program exit?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I am doing some experiments on memory. The first problem I met is how to allocate given amount of memory during runtime, say 500MB. I need the program's process hold it until the program exit.

I guess there may be several ways to achieve this? I prefer a simple but practical one.

Comment: Have you tried -Xmx / -Xms?

Comment: What's the point of simply allocating a block of memory? What problem are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: I think you can't unless you run a custom JVM. However, what's wrong with the default memory management?

Comment: Simpy allocate an `byte []` of the wanted size and fill it with random data. And at the end of the program calculate e.g. the sum of all elements. This way you ensure that the array is not removed by VM or compiler optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Java hides memory management from you, so there are two answers to your question:

1. Create the data structures of this size, you are going to need and hold a reference to them in some thread, until the program exits, because, once there is no reference to data on the heap in an active thread it becomes garbage collectable. On a 32-bit system 500MB should be roughly enough for an int array of 125000 cells, or 125 int arrays of 1000 cells.
2. If you just want to have the memory allocated and available, but not filled up, then start the virtual machine with -Xms=512M. This is going to make the VM allocate 512 M of memory for your program on startup, but it is going to be empty (just allocated) until you need it (do point 1). Xmx sets the maximum allocatable memory by your program.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   final byte[] x = new byte[500*1024     ]; // 500 Kbytes
   final byte[] y = new byte[500*1024*1024]; // 500 Mbytes
   ...
   System.out.println( x.length + y.length );
}
```

Comment: Java compiler might omit above lines for optimization if it sees that x and y are not used. At the end of the main method do something like this. `if(System.currentTimeMillis() < 1 ){System.out.println(x[Random.nextInt()%y.length]);}`

Answer (score 0):

[jmalloc](http://code.google.com/p/jmalloc/) lets you do it, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you're truly an expert.  You're giving up something that's central to Java - garbage collection.  You might as well be writing C.

Java NIO allocates byte buffers off heap this way.  I think this is where Oracle is going for memory mapping JARs and getting rid of perm gen, too.